# What is the non-correlation test in scipy.stats.pearsonr(x, y)?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, correlation

From http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html

> scipy.stats.pearsonr(x, y)
>
> Calculates a Pearson correlation coefficient and the p-value for
> **testing non-correlation**.
>
> ...
>
> The p-value roughly indicates the probability of an uncorrelated
> system producing datasets that have a Pearson correlation at least as
> extreme as the one computed from these datasets. The p-values are not
> entirely reliable but are probably reasonable for datasets larger than
> 500 or so.

What is the non-correlation test that `scipy.stats.pearsonr(x, y)` implements?

In particular, is the p-value necessarily smaller when the magnitude of the Pearson correlation coefficient is bigger? (That is the reason I want to know what the non-correlation test is and how its test statistic is calculated).

Whether you do or don't know what test is implemented in the function, could you tell me what are some commonly used tests for non-correlation? (Just for me to learn this subject)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia page on Pearson correlation [lists some examples of hypothesis tests based on the Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Inference).

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/02ece772f890b05b3d7f634775965f02d8724d4e/scipy/stats/mstats_basic.py#L398-L402), `scipy.stats.pearsonr` uses an approximation based on Student's t-distribution:

```
if r is masked or abs(r) == 1.0:
    prob = 0.
else:
    t_squared = (df / ((1.0 - r) * (1.0 + r))) * r * r
    prob = _betai(0.5*df, 0.5, df/(df + t_squared))

return r, prob
```

Here, `_betai(0.5*df, 0.5, df/(df + t_squared))` evaluates the [cumulative distribution function of Student's t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function).

The p-value represents a test of the null hypothesis that *x* and *y* are uncorrelated, i.e. that the true population correlation coefficient is zero. Sample correlation coefficients close to zero (i.e. weak correlation) will therefore tend to give you large p-values, and coefficients close to 1 or -1 (i.e. strong positive/negative correlation) will give small p-values.